# Default Storage for room database

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

Whenever we extend a RoomDatabase to Create a Database Instance

Where  does it gets stored by default

Local storage,

External Storage,

In Memory

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in the same location that `SQLiteOpenHelper` uses, in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) at the location given by `getDatabasePath()` on `Context`.